# Send multiple attachments via custom PHP form

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, email, php, zend-framework

We try to send attachments via a custom form. With the sendemailAction() in our IndexController.php we upload the files to a directory on the server and send them with the email.

```
public function sendemailAction()
{
    $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
    $mail = new Zend_Mail();
    $senderemail = $params['email'];
    $bodytext = '
        <p><strong>Klachtenformulier Type 1, Over het product</strong></p>
        <p>Naam: ' . $params['name'] . '</p>
        <p>Telefoon: ' . $params['telephone'] . '</p>
        <p>E-mail: ' . $params['email'] . '</p>
        <p>Ordernummer: ' . $params['ordernumber'] . '</p>
        <p>Klacht: ' . $params['comment'] . '</p>';
    $mail->setBodyHtml( $bodytext );
    $mail->setFrom('info@sitename.nl', 'Sitename.nl');
    $mail->addTo('michael.van.eijden@gmail.com', 'Michael van Eijden');
    $mail->setSubject('Subject');

    for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['file']['name']); $i++) {

        $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i];

        if ($tmpFilePath != ""){
            $newFilePath = "./media/complaintsuploads/" . $_FILES['file']['name'][$i];

            if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)) {
                $fname = $_FILES['file']['name'][$i];
                $ftempname = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i];                   
                $at = $mail->createAttachment(file_get_contents($ftempname));
                $at->disposition = Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_INLINE;
                $at->encoding = Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64;
                $at->filename = $fname;
            }
        }
    }

    try {
        $mail->send();
    }

    catch(Exception $ex) {
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Unable to send email.');
    }

    $this->_redirect('complaints-type-one-success');
}
```

Unfortunately this only sends the name of the added files. How we can get the size and type too?

Comment: Could you include the full email code and not just the attachment creation.

Comment: Please see the edited post

Comment: Have you tried creating a new Zend_Mime_Part attachment and adding each one individually?

Comment: I tried. Each one individually is working but does not solve because we provide possibility to add as much as file attachments as the front-end visitor wants.

Comment: What about if you created a new Zend_Mime_Part object for each iteration of the loop?

Comment: Sounds good. Can you help me to achieve that? I'm not a PHP programmer and mainly have to use examples from the internet ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have noticed that there is no type assigned to your attachments maybe you could also try adding that as well as using Zend_Mime_Part and using the $newFilePath as the attachment.

You could try the following including your file type

```
for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['file']['name']); $i++) {

    $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i];

    if ($tmpFilePath != ""){
        $newFilePath = "./media/complaintsuploads/" . $_FILES['file']['name'][$i];

        if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)) {
            $fname = $_FILES['file']['name'][$i];
            $ftempname = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i];                   
            $at = new Zend_Mime_Part(file_get_contents($newFilePath));
            $at->disposition = Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_INLINE;
            $at->encoding = Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64;
            $at->filename = $fname;

            $mail->addAttachment($at);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi David. Thanks but unfortantely changed nothing. I also tried to set the size with $at->size. Seems like the type and size not retrieved in the for.

Comment: Interesting, did you say it works for one file but not multiple? Do the files under /media folder also work if you open it?

Comment: It works for one file. The files under the media folder work when I open it. Just found out that the file type is correctly retrieved with $_FILES['file']['type']; but $_FILES['file']['size']; is not working.

Comment: Is there anything under $_FILES['file']['error'] error types can be found at http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: $_FILES['file']['error'] is null

Comment: Interesting, if it was for multiple then the error type and size should all be arrays, you could try attaching the file from the $newFilePath if the upload itself is working.

Comment: That works! I tried to attach from the $newFilePath earlier but without the Zend_Mime_Part. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem I will update my answer to include this.

Comment: $at->type should be removed too

Comment: yup updated, glad it helped you out